# Check if memberfunction returns temporary object or array object

Tags: c++

I have an array of class objects and want to check if the object that im trying to add, already exisits inside the array. The comparison is done via a uniqueIDString. If the comparison is true I want to return the matching object, if not I want to return a new instance of the class.

```
    Classobject stock::checkIfItemExists(Classobject object) {
       for(int i = 0; i < stock.getSize(); i++) {
          if(compareUniqueIDs(object, stock[i]) {
               return stock[i]; 
          }
       }
       return Classobject{} // no similar item found, return new Classobject
   }
```

Is there a possibility that the calling function can distinguish between the return value of a arrayelement (`stock[i]`) and the return of a newly created classobject (`Classobject{}`)?

Comment: It depends entirely on what `Classobject` is and whether it can have a defalt value in your array. Maybe you're looking for `std::optional`?

Comment: This sounds awfully close to a std::map to me...

Comment: I would expect an "if exist" function to return true or false and not an object.
Perhaps you should use a form like `bool stock::checkIfItemExists(
Classobjet object, 
Classobject *existingObject);`? And try to avoid copying objects. Use `const Classobject& object` for the first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you imbue some kind of information into the `Classobject{}` instance, the caller will not be able to distinguish.

An old-fashioned, but still effective, way of dealing with this is to change the return type to a

```
std::pair<bool, Classobject>
```

and return `true` as the first item in the pair, say, if an object was created. A more modern way, from C++17, would be to change the return type to

```
std::optional<Classobject>
```

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional